# Word Inline spellcheck not working

Tags: microsoft-word

Yo,

I'm using whatever the latest version of word it, and it lacks those squiggly red lines that identify spelling errors. How can I turn that feature back on?

Answer (score 1):

File -> Options -> Proofing -> "When correcting spelling and grammar in Word" -> "Check spelling as you type"